# MAAttachedWindow for NSStatusItem without a custom view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I have a simple app that has a NSStatusItem, which only displays an icon.

I would now like to add functionality that would make a `MAAttachedWindow` appear under the NSStatusItem.

I saw the demo code Matt Gemmel provided; the code he uses to make the `MAAttachedWindow` appear under the NSStatusItem is:

```
NSRect frame = [[self window] frame];
NSPoint pt = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(frame), NSMinY(frame));
[controller toggleAttachedWindowAtPoint:pt];
```

The above is done in the custom view of the `NSStatusItem`. However, my `NSStatusItem` has no custom view. How can I add the `MAAttachedWindow` in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't afaik. You have to have a way to get coordinates to attach the window to, and the only way i've been able to get that to work is to use a custom view so you can get the coordinates on mouse down and the only way i've seen is to use your own view. Anything else would probably be a little hacky unless there is some way to get the view for a status item without a custom view and it wouldn't be good to display the MSAttachedWindow and a menu.

I just settled on doing a NSStatusitem with a custom view and faking selection by drawing a background gradient when its selected.

Comment: You can use the undocumented -(NSWindow *)_window on the status item, assuming of course that you don't plan submitting it to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using NSPopover ?